# Position a JButton properly within a GridBagLayout | Java 8

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I want to position a `JButton` "Start" in the lower center of my GUI.
Sadly the `GridBagConstraints` that I set seem to have no effect.
I'm working with `jdk1.8.0_191` and the `Eclipse IDE`.

EDIT: I switched my snippet to a "minimal reproducible example".
Here the snippet of my code:

```
package gui.main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
        frame.setSize(646, 509);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setTitle("Adventure Time");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 5;
            
                JButton button = new JButton("Start");  
                button.setBackground(Color.black);      
                button.setForeground(Color.white);  
                button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 60));
                button.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(110, 60));
                button.setVisible(true);
                
            panel.add(button, gbc);
            panel.setVisible(true);
        
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
    }
}
```

Here is a picture where I approximately want the "Start" Button instead.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps [BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) is more appropriate?

Comment: It's too bad you didn't provide a  [mre].  I could have copied the code into my Eclipse IDE and tried different ideas.

Comment: thank you for the input Gilbert; I will transform my question
and @Abra I will read some documents on BoxLayout thank you aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a simple, runnable example of a GUI with a start button on the lower fourth of the `JPanel`.  Here's the example GUI.

[image: Start button GUI]

Use Swing components.  Don't extend Swing components, or any other Java class, unless you intend to override one of the methods in the class.

I used a `BorderLayout` for the `JPanel`.  I used a calculated empty border to shift the start button down from the center.

I set the size of the `JPanel` in this example.  I'm assuming you'll set the size of the game panel based on the size of your image.

Here's the code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class StartButtonExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new StartButtonExample());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        Dimension panelSize = new Dimension(400, 400);
        panel.setPreferredSize(panelSize);

        JButton button = new JButton("Start");
        Dimension buttonSize = button.getPreferredSize();

        int height = panelSize.height - buttonSize.height;
        int width = panelSize.width - buttonSize.width;
        int top = height * 3 / 4;
        int left = (width - buttonSize.width) / 2;
        int bottom = height / 4;
        int right = left;
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
                top, left, bottom, right));

        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return panel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is it also feasible with GridBagConstraints?

Comment: @Georodin: You could create 6 or 7 "new JLabel(" ");" and use the gridy parameter to place each label on its own line, then place the JButton.

Comment: thank you so the gridbaglayout ignores empty rows? I used now 
  ´for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
   super.add(new JPanel(), gbc);
   gbc.gridy++;
  }´

I could size the JPanel or give it more ywidth at once to not iterate 20x times but it works for now

Answer (score 1):

In my amateurish opinion:

I ended up using different `insets` for my small application.
It is more clean looking in my opinion.

```
   //margin 400 top, rest 3
   gbc.insets = new Insets(400,3,3,3);
   gbc.gridy = 0;
   getWrapperPanel().add(getBtnStart02(), gbc);
    
   //margin 3 at all sides for all following gui objects
   gbc.insets = new Insets(3,3,3,3);
   gbc.gridy = 1;
   getWrapperPanel().add(getBtnLoad(), gbc);
```

Works like a charm.